# Acer TravelMate P645-MG 3G modem isn't recoginized

Tags: acer, usb-modem, 3g

I got a new laptop Acer TravelMate P-645-MG with a builtin 3G card.

I can see the modem in `dmesg`

```
[    5.550759] usb 2-5: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[    5.569075] usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1570
[    5.569076] usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=5, Product=4, SerialNumber=0
[    5.569078] usb 2-5: Product: HUAWEI Mobile Broadband Module
[    5.569079] usb 2-5: Manufacturer: Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
[    6.434521] usb 2-5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[    6.442747] usb 2-5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[    6.443201] usb 2-5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[    7.589287] usb 2-5: USB disconnect, device number 6
```

The disconnect line looks very suspicious.

But it doesn't show up in `lsusb`

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1c7a:0603 LighTuning Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c57 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 032: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And as a result I can't see it in NetworkManager